# Error: no input file specified. Laravel with docker nginx-proxy

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

probably somebody faced this issue.
Through the time I get error "no input file specified" from nginx.
There is the log from nginx container "FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/public/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream".

It happens only for https, on local machine allright.

[There is a full log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHdFf.png)

As you can see, sometimes I got response 200, sometimes 404, from same file.

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
index index.php index.html index.htm;
root /var/www/public;

location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    allow all;
    root /var/www;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

rewrite ^/core/authorize.php/core/authorize.php(.*)$ /core/authorize.php$1;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off; access_log off;
}
location = /robots.txt {
    log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
}
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

}

Comment: Does `/var/www/public/index.php` exist?

Comment: For the 404, maybe it's being generated by something in your code, with `abort(404)`?

Comment: @aynber In logs u can see that one route give different response. One time I'm getting page, but another one nginx doesn't see index.php, but the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have been solved the problem. Instead nginx I set up apache, because laravel 5.8 refuses to work with nginx. Latest version of laravel works properly with nginx in docker